# How to filter options using check boxes in custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hello I am trying to make a filter on advanced custom field that will filter out accommodations based on the checked boxes. Whenever I run the filter it does not filter and shows the else statement

**My Code**

```
if($_destination == "All") {
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                                    'posts_per_page'=>10,
                                    'post_type'=> 'accommodation',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'orderby' => 'date',
                                    'order'   => 'ASC',
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'amenities',
                                    'value' => serialize(array($_amenities)),
                                    'compare' => '=',
                                        )
                                        ),
                                    's' => $_name,
                                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                        );                          
                    } else {
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                                'posts_per_page'=>10,
                                'post_type'=> 'accommodation',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'order'   => 'ASC',
                                's' => $_name,
                                
                                'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                        );                      
                    }                   
                }
```

**Check Box**

```
<ul class="ks-cboxtags">
                            <li><input name="amenities-application[]" type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" value="AC" <?php  if( in_array("AC", $_POST['amenities-application'])) { echo "checked=\"checked\"";  }?>><label for="checkboxOne">AC</label></li>
                            <li><input name="amenities-application[]" type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo" value="Bar/Lounge"  <?php  if( in_array ("Bar\Lounge", $_POST['amenities-application'])) { echo "checked=\"checked\"";  }?>><label for="checkboxTwo">Bar</label></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Check what value present in `$_destination` variable.

Comment: I think you are not getting the values and due to that, it is not working. You html is saying the field name is amenities-application while in php code I couldn't find the value or vairable which is storing the value of amenities-application

Comment: $_destination is not getting any values.